# What is the terminal command to retrieve files from a remote server using ssh in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, download, remote, upload

I normally ssh into my remote server in order to administrate my files using terminal for Mac OS X.

I don't understand how I retrieve (download) files from the server to my local computer, or send files from my local computer to the server (upload).

Answer (score 22):

To grab a file over SSH:

```
$ scp host:/path/to/file local_file
```

To send a file:

```
$ scp local_file host:/path/to/file
```

`scp` is "secure copy", a copy utility that sends files over an SSH connection.

Comment: there's also `sftp`, which is kind of like `ftp`, but uses `ssh` as the actual means of communication.